# store the localstorage value in the form of json

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to save some input[type="text"] and input[type="hidden"] values in local storage. Below is the JS:

```
$('.proceed_btn').on('click', function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){    
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var value = $(this).val();
      localStorage.setItem(id, value);
    }); 
    $('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){    
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var value = $(this).val();
      localStorage.setItem(id, value);
    }); 

});
```

The value are getting stored perfectly. But I want to store these value in json format. But how to save both these values in one variable. For example:

```
order: {
   id: '', 
   product: '',
   service: '',
   name: ''
}
```

I have checked the JSON stringify but how to implement with different types of input together

Comment: I was trying something forgot to remove the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply build an object and then `stringify` it. For instance, if I assume the `name` of your `input` elements is the name you want to use on your object:

```
$('.proceed_btn').on('click', function(){
    // Blank to start with
    var order = {};

    // Loop through all inputs...
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="text"]').each(function(){
      // ...adding their values as properties
      order[this.name] = this.value;
    }); 

    // Store that object in JSON format
    localStorage.setItem("order", JSON.stringify(order));
});
```

Later if you want to retrieve it and set the inputs based on its values:

```
var order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("order") || "null");
if (order) {
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        if (this.name in order) {
            this.value = order[this.name];
        } else {
            this.value = "";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing as this. This should solve OP's issue. And to check if browser supports LocalStorage `if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined')`

Comment: Its not printing anything in local storage

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 parameters will be there while writing localstorage:

ex.
localStorage.setItem( 'car', car );
1st parameter is key actually and 2nd parameter is value;

You have passed 3 paramters which is wrong.

If you can to store multiple values in localstorage, create object of that values and write that object to localstorage:

```
ex.

var car = {};
car.wheels = 4;
car.doors = 2;
car.sound = 'vroom';
car.name = 'Lightning McQueen';
console.log( car );
localStorage.setItem('car', JSON.stringify(car));
console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'car' ) ) );
```

Comment: Okie, but how to store these value in one variable in jason format

Comment: I have updated answer above and described how to store multiple values in json format

Comment: @PreetyAngel: It's JSON. Not JASON or jason. **J**ava**S**cript**O**bject**N**otation.

Comment: You can do like localStorage.setItem('car', JSON.stringify(car));

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.

```
var objectToSave = {};
$('.proceed_btn').on('click', function(){

$('input[type="text"],input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  var id = elem.attr('id');
  var value = elem.val();
  objectToSave[id] = value;
}); 
  localStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(objectToSave));
});
```

Comment: can you specify what actual string you need to save in localstorage. And is it not printing value only? what about id and type

Comment: I want these values to be stored in local storage as json format. date_slot
document_id
no-of-copies
product
service_id
stamp_amount

Comment: Iam getting this value in local storage Order:{"id":"no-of-copies","value":"0","type":"hidden"}

Comment: it worked :) than kyou as well as T.J Crowder code also worked :) thank you :)

Comment: So, you edited your answer to be a less-complete duplicate of my answer from 45 minutes earlier? Not really cool. @PreetyAngel: FYI

Comment: No I actually understood the problem later and proposed solution on my own. I didn't copied.

Comment: At the end of the day it comes down to the same thing. The answer was already here, duplicating it is not useful. But whatever.